# How can I benchmark/profile my PHP/MYSQL news site in order such I can compare it later on with a django/postgres recoded version?

Tags: php, mysql, django, postgresql, profiler

I'm looking for some type of profiling utility I could use where I can compare between 2 different setups with some sort of consistency factor. Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Apache - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/):

> Siege is a regression test and benchmark utility. It can stress test a single URL with a user defined number of simulated users, or it can read many URLs into memory and stress them simultaneously. The program reports the total number of hits recorded, bytes transferred, response time, concurrency, and return status. Siege supports HTTP/1.0 and 1.1 protocols, GET and POST directives, cookies, transaction logging, and basic authentication. Its features are configurable on a per user basis.

For profiling the applications themselves, you'd need a profiler for their respective languages, e.g. XDebug or ZendDebugger in PHP (don't know what's there for python).